# Want to a record a "score" when two objects collide XNA monogame

Tags: c#, collision, monogame

so I am to iterate counter by 1 every time a collision happens (between star object and planet object) but it ends up iterating a huge number.

```
            public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
            {

              int count = 0; 

              if (star.getBound().Intersects(planet.getBound()))
              {

                count += 1;

              }
            }
```

The problem is because is it update I think it keeps on iterating so I tried to put it in the draw function but it still increased by some huge amount.

Is there something wrong with the star object? Because in my star class after reaching a certain y position I just displace it.

```
       //inside update function of star object

        pos.Y += speed;
        Random random = new Random();

        if (pos.Y > 500)
        {
            pos = new Vector2(1 * random.Next(10, 700), 1 * random.Next(0, 200));


        }
```

I'm wondering if thats the problem instead of update and if the latter what do I do because when I tried to put it in draw it pretty much acted the same.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit confusing, but I'll try to do my best.

1) Both Update and Draw are called every frame. This is probably why you see it being called (iterating) every time.
2) You should never put logic code in the Draw method. This method should be kept as short as possible and only for rendering
3) Count is set to 0 every single time Update is called. You might want to make it a member of the class.

There isn't much more we can help you with with the small sample of code you gave. Please give us more information and we can try to give you a better answer.

Comment: Hi so I made an if statement that says it two objects intersect than an int has to be iterated by 1. But because that if statement is inside an updated method (of my class that records intersections/collisions) the int iterates by more than one. SO I guess I have to move the if intersects from the update but then put it where?

Comment: It is correct to put the if statement in that method. You just need to take into account that the method will be called for everyframe. If you don't want it to be detected more than once, you will need to add more logic that check if there was already a collision with that object.

Answer (score 0):

Think of `Update()` as a While loop that keeps running until the game stops.

```
while (true /*game is running*/) {
    int count = 0;

    if (star.getBound().Intersects(planet.getBound())) {
        count += 1;
    }
}
```

Now you will start to see some problems here:

- `count` is constantly reset back to 1. (Just remove that statement)
- It checks if the star is *currently* colliding with the planet.
  It doesn't care if it is already collding before!

To solve the latter issue, you can use a boolean as a state to determine if the star is already colliding or not, then determine the actions to take, like so:

```
bool isColliding = false;

public override void Update(GameTime gameTime) {
    if (!isColliding) {
        // Was not colliding, just started colliding.
        if (star.getBound().Intersects(planet.getBound())) {
            count += 1;
            isColliding = true;
        }
    } else {
        // Was colliding, just stopped colliding.
        if (!star.getBound().Intersects(planet.getBound())) {
            isColliding = false;
        }
    }
}
```

This allows the code to add a score, only if the star and the planet just started colliding with each other.